# Creating generic list from LINQ query with multiple instances of descendant element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, parsing

I am attempting to parse an XML file retrieved from a GET request to an online dictionary API with LINQ.

The file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry_list version="1.0">
    <entry id="nanny">
        <ew>nanny</ew>
        <hw>nan*ny</hw>
        <sound>
            <wav>nanny001.wav</wav>
            <wpr>!na-nE</wpr>
        </sound>
        <vr>
            <vl>also</vl>
            <va>nan*nie</va>
            <sound>
                <wav>nanny001.wav</wav>
                <wpr>!na-nE</wpr>
            </sound>
            <pr>ˈna-nē</pr>
        </vr>
        <fl>noun</fl>
        <in>
            <il>plural</il>
            <if>nannies</if>
        </in>
        <et>probably of baby-talk origin</et>
        <def>
            <date>1795</date>
            <dt>:a child's nurse or caregiver</dt>
        </def>
    </entry>
    <entry id="nanny goat">
        <ew>nanny goat</ew>
        <subj>AG#ZM</subj>
        <hw>nanny goat</hw>
        <fl>noun</fl>
        <et>
            <it>Nanny,</it>
            nickname for
            <it>Anne</it>
        </et>
        <def>
            <date>1788</date>
            <dt>:a female goat</dt>
        </def>
    </entry>
</entry_list>
```

I am trying to parse only the first instance of 'def', because it is the only instance to match the original word to be defined. I am unsure how to achieve this. It is also possible for the 'def' block to look like this:

```
<def>
    <date>13th century</date>
    <sn>1</sn>
    <dt>
        :a person who puts on a false appearance of
        <d_link>virtue</d_link>
        or religion
    </dt>
    <sn>2</sn>
    <dt>
        :a person who acts in contradiction to his or her stated beliefs or feelings
    </dt>
</def>
```

In which case I'm unsure how to take the 'sn' & 'dt' groups and put them in a format that easily outputs them as the couples they originally were. My current code is here:
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create([the request url]);
    request.Method = "GET";

```
string responseStr;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream _stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_stream);
    responseStr = sr.ReadToEnd();

    sr.Close();
    _stream.Close();
}

XDocument xdoc;

using (StringReader s = new StringReader(responseStr)) {
    xdoc = XDocument.Load(s);
}

string word = (string)xdoc.Element("ew");
string pron = (string)xdoc.Element("pr");
string pos = (string)xdoc.Element("fl");

Console.WriteLine((string)xdoc.Element("sr"));

var definitions = (from d in xdoc.Root.Descendants("def")
    select new {
        entryNum = xdoc.Elements("sr").Select(a => a.Value).ToList(),
        entryDef = xdoc.Elements("dt").Select(a => a.Value).ToList()
    }).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(":", definitions.entryDef)); //output is blank
```

and this is the output:

```
{ entryNum = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String], entryDef = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] }
```

I have tried to output the contents of the child lists, but the output is blank and shows no value.

The output I'd like to achieve is a generic list with contents as so: `{entryNum:entryDef, entryNum:entryDef}` so I can easily output it as such:

> 1. a child's nurse or caregiver
> 2. another definition here

Comment: Are you able to modify the XML format at all? It's not a terribly useful format at the moment, IMO. You could use `Zip` to zip together the `sn` and `dt` elements, but it's far from ideal.

Comment: It's an http response from a GET request to a dictionary API, so I can't modify it. I'll add in that bit to make it more clear

Comment: Provide details of the expected outcome format and i believe definitions need to be as 

`var definitions = (from d in xdoc.Root.Descendants("def")
    select new {
        entryNum = d.Elements("sr").Select(a => a.Value).ToList(),
        entryDef = d.Elements("dt").Select(a => a.Value).ToList()
    }).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Well the output isn't going to be a formatted string like that - it's going to be an object, but we don't know how you want that to be represented... and what if there are multiple `def` matches? Additionally, there's still not a short but complete example.

Comment: The entryNum & entryDef are of type List<string> and you need to convert the list to string by concatenating them to get string output.

Comment: I need to represent the data as: `entryNum. entryDef`, example: `1. This is the definition.`

As for the multiple `def` matches, that is another thing I am unsure how to handle.

The outputs of the list children's values are blank

Comment: Is it possible for you to serialize the response to an object ? If so then you can easily find out the desired node by simple for loop or LINQ

Comment: I've decided Merriam Webster has shite formatting for their httpresponse. I'm going to close this and choose a different API to draw definitions from. Thank you for the assistance thus far.